# Meaning of "in" phrase

Tags: meaning, prepositional-phrases

In the below sentence, does "in a major reversal" mean that the president's announcement is a major reversal, or that because the situation came into a major reversal, the president made such an announcement? It comes at 8:00 in an NBC News clip,

[> Tonight, **in** a major reversal, President Biden announcing he's sending 31 powerful American Abrams tanks to Ukraine, a move the Pentagon had resisted for months.](https://archive.org/download/KNTV_20230126_000000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt/KNTV_20230126_000000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt.mp4?t=0/60&ignore=x.mp4)

Comment: It means that the President has changed his mind in a big way.

Comment: There wasn't "a major reversal" already going on when Biden made his announcement, so it's NOT exactly like *Yesterday on the White House lawn, **in a thunderstorm**, Biden announced that he was getting wet*.

Comment: The sentence contains an error; should "announcing" instead be "is announcing" or "announced"? Also, the link is incorrect. (The video it contains is only :59 long and doesn't include anything about Biden.)